# Magento 2: How we can hide duplicate coupon details (label and amount) from order invoice pdf?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, coupon-codes, invoice-pdf

I want to hide cart price rule applied coupon code details (Label and amount) from order invoice pdf:
[image]

I tried to hide this by applying condition on label wise but It's not working and it's failing with other coupon code label.

If anyone have the solution for this please share

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a plugin for method `getTotalsForDisplay()` in the next class:
`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/DefaultTotal.php`

Declare the plugin in your `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`:

```xml
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal">
    <plugin name="disable_totals_discount_pdf" type="Vendor/Module/Plugin/DefaultTotalPlugin" />
</type>
```

And inside your plugin:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\DefaultTotal;

class DefaultTotalPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param DefaultTotal $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetTotalsForDisplay(DefaultTotal $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->getSourceField() === 'discount_amount') {
            return [];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

This will do the trick for the `discount_amount` field, but you can do for every field that you want.